# Android - REST Web Service encrypted data sharing

Tags: java, android, rest

I need your help to create a safe connection between a client(Android) and a REST web service.

In my android-app, there will be a login, in which the user specifies their login name and password. The login name and password are sent to the web service. With the login data a connection to a application server should established, to access to several of beans...

**The question is how can I transfer the username and password encrypted from the Client(Android) to the Web Service(JAX-RS)?** HTTP basic authentication with SSL?

Can anyone of you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSL, but if this is the only piece of information you need to protect, just encrypt it using the java encryption libraries.